# ActionBar logo is not displaying in XXHDPI mobile device

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working with action bar and i want to customize the action bar logo. For that i have written code (below) but its working for ***Samsung*** and ***MicroMax*** devices but not for ***Lenovo K900*** and ***Sony Ericssion Xperia z1***. What should i do?

#### Api 16 its working fine but not in 17 (4.2)

Code:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/product_category_logo</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

#### Values-v14 Folder:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

#### Values-v11 Folder:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<!-- <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"><!-- Recent changes -->
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Guy i don't know what should i do. Please help me out.

Comment: @guys are you there??

Comment: have you tryed `parent="@style/Widget.Hol..."` instead of `parent="@android:style/Widget.Hol..."` ?

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: @Phil logo is not displaying... nothing is there.

Comment: have a folder drawable-xxhdpi in res folder?

Comment: Yes its there @ImtiyazKhalani

Comment: Please check you have same theme in values,values-11,values-14 folder?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar what should i check in these folder??

Comment: you have to check same theme applied in all these folders

Comment: <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <!-- <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> -->
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"><!-- Recent changes -->
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: Please tell me what wrong here?? @DhawalSodhaParmar

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar u there?

Comment: @user3154663: your problem solved?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar no man i was waiting for your reply at that day.

Comment: I was got appeared but theme was no working properly @DhawalSodhaParmar

Comment: but now you understand how use theme in different vaules folder?, then try to modify theme.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i have created different folders for 16 and 17 but when i am using this my action bar is working but whole thing is not and when i am using the AppTheme everything is working except actionBar but only in 16 API (Samsung and micromax ia have tested) not in 4.2 (Lenovo K900)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) project in your application. Because this project already handles this kind of things for you.

**And just for the sake of verification**, Google is also using this ActionBar in its [Google I/O app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.iosched&hl=en).

You can also download this project from [GitHub ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) which also includes demo versions of this `open source project`.

**To add ActionBarSherlock to your project:**

Simply git clone the repo from GitHub in your workspace. And then import it as -> create project from existing source in Eclipse.

After this go to Project->Properties->Android and Add it as Library.

Here is your answer for importing it: [Importing Actionbarsherlock into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208356/importing-actionbarsherlock-into-eclipse)

And after importing it look for the Sample projects in it, how they are making use of Sherlock Action Bar. You will get a lot of info from there.

*Most important thing about ActionBarSherlock is that you can also use it for Android OS below 3.0 but official Android API provide Action Bar widget only above OS v3.0. So you can target your app for all kind of users, those who are using OS above 3.0 and below 3.0, both will be targeted.*

Comment: Simply git clone the repo from GitHub in your workspace. And then import it as -> create project from existing source in Eclipse.

After this go to Project->Properties->Android and Add it as Library.

Comment: my android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19". tell me what should i do.

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757400/setting-actionbarsherlock-theme-for-android-app and try to customize your project like this. Also look for the SampleList's AndroidManifest.xml file and you will be able to run your project.

Answer (score 0):

### Please add below theme in all folder - **values,vaules-11values-14**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/product_category_logo</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

**i think you have to use actionbarsharelock or actionbarcompart for < android 3.0**

but first put this theme in values-11,values-14 and test the app.

also use theme `MyActionBar` in android manifest file.

try and let me k'no

Comment: you want me to copy paste every thing from Values/style.xml  ??

Comment: MyActionBar where in manifest file

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:logo="@style/MyActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: when i changed the  android:theme="@style/AppTheme to android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" my whole theme got messed up.\

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47758/discussion-between-dhawal-sodha-parmar-and-user3154663)

Comment: Yes its coming but whole theme got messed up?? @dhawal Sodha Parmar

Comment: please write a comment when ever you will be free. @dhawal Sodha Parmar