# Many errors imported a project to eclipse

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I imported a project to eclipse
but I have many errors.

[view screenshot](http://uphinhnhanh.com/images/2730vkl.jpg)

I tried to change the Java compile level from api 1.6 to 1.7
but it did not work for me.

I am using this code.
[open source](https://github.com/kmonaghan/Broadsheet.ie-Android)

Comment: What are errors reported by eclipse?

Comment: [here screenshot](http://www.uphinhnhanh.com/images/20049vkll.jpg)
just import, i don't change anything code
help me fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't have import the library ActionBarSherlock and you are using in the project.

Comment: how to import libary actionbarsherlock?
import java build patch or import to mainactivity
i'm newbie
thank you

Comment: This link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208356/importing-actionbarsherlock-into-eclipse

Comment: thanks.import library actionbarsherlock worked. And you can help me fix `No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.`
code : `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">`